# How to save the data in the database using mongoose/mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My code consists of `server.js` file to create a Node+ Express server api.
The server.js file consists of models that I have created and the routes with `GET`, `POST` methods.

`server.js`

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var cors = require('cors');
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/contactlist');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/vnd.api+json'}));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());


app.use(function(req,res,next){

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

var contactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    email:String,
    number:Number,
    address:String
});

var Contact = mongoose.model("Contact", contactSchema);


//Routers
//get
app.get('/contacts',function(req,res){
    console.log('inside get router fetching the contacts');

    Contact.find({},function(err, contacts){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(contacts);
    });

});

//post---->get

app.post('/contacts',function(req,res){
    console.log('creating the contacts');

    Contact.create({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        number:req.body.number,
        address:req.body.address,
        done: false
    },function(err,contact){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);

        Contact.find({},function(err,contact){
            if(err)
            res.send(err);
            res.json(contact);
        });
    });
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('App listening on port 8080');
```

Then I have created my service class where I fetch my data from server. I don't have any problem in this. It is working absolutely fine.

Then comes my 2 pages where in the first page I create a contact list and in the second page I get that list from the server/db.

That why am I not able to get the data from the db and post the correct data. The data that is posted in the db contains only Id and -v flag.

[image: logs]

Answer (score 2):

What I would do to debug is to set the mongoose debug option

mongoose.set('debug', true) // enable logging collection methods + arguments to the console.

Im am suspecting that your models schema isn't properly defined.

The log output should give you a hit as to why its not saving correctly.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var mySchema = new Schema({
    // my props
});
```

mongoose.model('MyModel', mySchema);
// mySchema is

and after you call mongoose.connect you can use your model like so

```
var BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost');
```

Comment: Yup you need to define your models schema. If its not defined by default mongoose just inserts _id

Comment: ok..then it means without schema we don't define models.right?

Comment: Correct before you use your models you need to define how they should look. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/model-definition.html .

Comment: will try and close the question..:) thank you for helping:)

Comment: Hi, after creating schema the same problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about query object:

```
Contact.find({}, function(err, contacts){
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json(contacts);
    });
```